# carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id returns me 404

Tags: checkout, api, magento2.4

In my local environment, when I go to checkout, it throws me an error, and reviewing the console, I detected it is caused because the call to this endpoint returns me a 404:

> **carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id returns**

As I saw, it is because the request URL is adding the "checkout" parameter to the URL. I mean, the normal request should be:

> http://*[base
> URL]*/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id

But in this environment is constructed like this:

> http://*[base
> URL]*/**checkout**/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id

Adding the "checkout" word after the base URL. I think it is because is adding the full URL of the site as the base URL:

> http://*[base URL]*/checkout/

But I don't understand why. It only happens in my local environment, not in production or staging. Did you know why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any customization involving the javascript that makes that api request?

What should happen is that `getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsByAddressId` is called in `Magento_Checkout::js/model/resource-url-manager.js` which calls to `createUrl` in `Magento_Checkout::js/model/url-builder.js` to build the rest api request url. One place you'll see this request being built is in `Magento_Checkout::js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js`.